# Override both foreign key and references in gorm

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I defined two DB structs

```golang
type Main struct {
    gorm.Model
    GroupID   int64  `gorm:"column:group_id"`
    GroupName string `gorm:"column:group_name"`
    ItemID    string `gorm:"column:item_id"`
    Item      Item   `gorm:"foreignKey:ItemID;references:item_id"`
}

type Item struct {
    gorm.Model
    ItemID   string `gorm:"column:item_id"`
    ItemName string `gorm:"column"item_name"`
}
```

However, when I do a select, i.e.

```golang
mains := make([]*Main, 0)
db.Where(someFilters).Preload("Item").Find(&mains)
```

I get the queries

```sql
SELECT * FROM mains WHERE condition1='condition_value';
SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_id IN (1, 2); # Uses Main's ID field as the argument instead
```

The IN query uses the primary key `id` of the `Main` struct instead of using the field `item_id`. Am I doing something wrong here? I just want to get the "joined" result via `item_id` , i.e. I want the second query to be

```sql
SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_id IN (`main_1_item_id`, `main_2_item_id`);
```

UPDATE: Also tried changing the tag to `association_foreign_key`

```golang
type Main struct {
    gorm.Model
    GroupID   int64  `gorm:"column:group_id"`
    GroupName string `gorm:"column:group_name"`
    ItemID    string `gorm:"column:item_id"`
    Item      Item   `gorm:"association_foreignkey:ItemID;references:item_id"`
}
```

Now the generated SQL is

```sql
SELECT * FROM mains WHERE condition1='condition_value';
SELECT * FROM items WHERE id IN (`main_1_item_id`, `main_2_item_id`); # Uses Main's ItemID field but using Item's ID field as query
```

**References:**

[1] https://gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution to my problem.

The gorm tags should be

```golang
type Main struct {
    gorm.Model
    GroupID   int64  `gorm:"column:group_id"`
    GroupName string `gorm:"column:group_name"`
    ItemID    string `gorm:"column:item_id"`
    Item      Item   `gorm:"associationForeignKey:ItemID;foreignKey:ItemID"`
}

type Item struct {
    gorm.Model
    ItemID   string `gorm:"column:item_id"`
    ItemName string `gorm:"column"item_name"`
}
```

Now the generated SQL queries are

```sql
SELECT * FROM mains WHERE condition1='condition_value';
SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_id IN (`main_1_item_id`, `main_2_item_id`);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple ideas you might want to look into:

First: Since you have an `Item` struct inside your `Main` struct, why are you using a second field for `ItemID`, you already have one in Item struct. Gorm is pretty good at handling associations automatically, try simply embedding the `Item` struct in `Main` struct.

Second: when you embed `gorm.Model`, it declares its `Id` field as the primary key of the struct, that might also cause a problem.